# Stop processing single line in awk after successful match?

Tags: awk

Is there a way to stop processing a single line in awk? Is there something like `break` or `continue` that works on pattern-action pairs rather than control structures within an action?

Suppose I have the following `input.txt` file and I'm trying to replace each of the names with `x0`, `x1`, `x2`, `...`. However, I want to leave lines beginning with a space or `-` alone.

```
-- data
bob     4
joe     5
bob     6
joe     7
```

becomes:

```
-- data
x0 4
x1 5
x0 6
x1 7
```

And I have the following script that does it. (As a side note, there's probably a better way of structuring this using a heredoc rather than a massive string literal).

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '
    BEGIN { c = 0; }

    # do not process lines beginning with - or space
    /^[- ]/ {
        print;
    }

    # update 
    /^[^- ]/ {
        if (! ($1 in name) ) {
            new_name = "x" c;
            c += 1;
            name[$1] = new_name;
        }
        $1 = name[$1];
        print;
    }
' input.txt
```

This script leaves a bit to be desired. First of all, we know that `/^[- ]/` and `/^[^- ]/` are mutually exclusive, but that property isn't enforced anywhere. I'd like to be able to use something like `break` to abandon processing the line after the first match.

```
/^[- ]/ {
    print;
    break;
}
```

I'd like to be able to add another clause to alert the user to a problem if there is a non-empty line that doesn't match either of the first two patterns.

```
/./ {
    print "non-empty line!" > "/dev/stderr"
    # or print "non-empty line!" > "/dev/tty" if portability is a concern
}
```

However, if I add this pattern-action pair to the script as-is it fires after every non-empty line.

Is there something I can add after the first two test cases to stop processing the line since it has been "successfully" handled? If that isn't possible, is there a common awk idiom for a catch-all case?

Comment: [The `next` Statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Next-Statement)?

Comment: @steeldriver ...yes. I completely missed that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may use the `awk` statement `next` to immediately continue with processing the next input record.

Here's an alternative implementation of your `awk` script:

```bash
awk '/^[- ]/ { print; next } !($1 in n) { n[$1] = sprintf("x%d", c++) } { $1 = n[$1]; print }' data.in
```

The `awk` code is

```c
/^[- ]/    { print; next }
!($1 in n) { n[$1] = sprintf("x%d", c++) }
           { $1 = n[$1]; print }
```

`c` is the counter.  It will be zero from the start.

`n` is the associative array holding the new labels/names. It is indexed with the data from the file's first field/column.

`!($1 in n)` will be true if the data in the first field has not already been assigned a new label/name.